# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions (Bottle) (Python)

Tags: python, routes, bottle

I've written this code and then ran it via the CMD. However when I ran the code this occurred.

```
Bottle v0.12.18 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:80/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bottle_01.py", line 7, in <module>
    run(host='localhost', port = 80, debug=True)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\BottleWebApp\bottle.py", line 3137, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\BottleWebApp\bottle.py", line 2789, in run
    srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, app, server_cls, handler_cls)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 154, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Now I asked my professor but he's unfamiliar with the issue himself. I searched stackoverflow and I tried to disable my firewall but that didn't seem to help. Any suggestions? Is it an administration issue perhaps? My original code is below.

```
from bottle import route, run, static_file

@route('/')

def index():
    return static_file('webpage_01.html' , root= 'C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/BottleWebApp')
run(host='localhost', port = 80, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this problem go away when you try port 8000 instead of 80?

You're trying to bind to port 80. I don't know Windows, but on Linux your code would fail because port 80 (like all ports below 1024) is privileged--only root can bind to them. That's why you'll see most tutorials and web framework defaults use a high port number, typically `8000` or `8080`.

References:

https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_port

Comment: WOW thank you so much. This works. My professor was pushing for us to use 80 but I'll let him know this works on my computer. I didn't know the port was the issue.